# How do HTTP redirect requests send cookies?

Tags: http, cookies

Say I have cookies `a1` and `a2` in my cookie jar and their domain is ".a.com".

I visit "https://a.com?redirect=https://b.com". The original HTTP request carries `Cookie` header: `a1=123; a2=456`.

When it redirects to "https://b.com":

1. Should it forward `Cookie` header: `a1=123; a2=456`? Depends on `SameSite` attribute?
2. If I have cookies `b1` and `b2` in my cookie jar and their domain is ".b.com", should they be picked up and append to `Cookie` header of the redirect request?
3. If the answer of both 1 and 2 are yes, what if I also have another `a1` cookie with domain ".b.com"? Should it replace the one scoped to ".a.com" in `Cookie` header?

Is it defined in some spec?

Comment: It turns out to be bug of WebKit. Otherwise, Cookie header won't be forward in redirects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cookies are domain specific. The cookies `a1` and `a2` from "a.com" won't be sent when the browser redirects to "b.com". When your browser follows the redirect, the only cookies included in the GET request to "b.com" will be those you already have from the "b.com" domain (`b1` and `b2`).

This is separate from the relatively new `SameSite` attribute for cookies, which helps control how browsers send cookies during cross-site requests (e.g. images from your site embedded in another site). The best explanation I have come across for the `SameSite` attribute is here: https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained/